# Filehelpers add footer to generated excel file

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using `Filehelpers` to write excel file.
It has property `TemplateFile`so i can use file as template for rows.

But how can I add footer there? I want to add summary there. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no functionality within FileHelpers to do this.

However, you should be able to extend the source code to provide it. Have a look at the [ExcelStorage.InsertRecords](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers.ExcelStorage/ExcelStorage.cs) routine.